# Continuity of f(x) = 4 if rational and x^2 if irrational

Tags: real-analysis

Find the points of discontinuity of the following function

f(x) = 4 if x is a rational number and x^2 if x is an irrational number

I know that the function will only be continuous at +/- 2. But I need to prove it. I am not sue how to go about it. I am sure we need to use the sequential criterion for continuity to show that lim f(xn) <> f(c) when lim xn = c. We can take a sequence of irrationals that converges to a rational number and a sequence of rationals that converges to an irrational. Is this right?

Comment: "I am sure we need to use the sequential criterion for continuity" Not at all. You can also use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ criterion, or the topological criterion (dealing with open sets and preimages). There are many ways to the goal here. But your approach seems sound from the looks of it.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it? Let us say there is a irrational sequence xn that converges to a rational number c. f(xn) = xn^2 so lim f(xn) = c^2. But f(c) = 4. So lim f(xn) <> f(c) as xn approaches c unless xn is very close to 2. Is this right? And similarly for a rational seqence converging to an irrational number

Answer (score 1):

**note:** it is not necessary to use sequential approach as pointed out in the comments. Perhaps you may have been asked to use that approach so here is what you can try.

**hint**

Suppose we want to check continuity at $x=c$. Choose a sequence $r_n$ of rational numbers that converge to $c$. Then for continuity, $f(r_n) \rightarrow f(c)$. Similarly if we choose a sequence $t_n$ of irrational numbers that converge to $c$. Then for continuity, $f(t_n) \rightarrow f(c)$.

In the case of rational sequence, $f(r_n)=4$. So this means $f(c)=4$. So if $c$ is a rational number, then we are all set because $f(c)=4$ by the definition of $f$. But then we will also need $t_n^2 \rightarrow 4$. This means $c=...$

Now ask yourself, what if $c$ is irrational?

Comment: Let us say there is a irrational sequence xn that converges to a rational number c. f(xn) = xn^2 so lim f(xn) = c^2. But f(c) = 4. So lim f(xn) <> f(c) as xn approaches c unless xn is very close to 2. Is this right? And similarly for a rational seqence converging to an irrational number

Comment: @AishwaryaDeore I am not sure what you mean when you use the notation <> ? The idea is $x_n^2 \rightarrow  c^2$ but by continuity,  $x_n^2$ also should converge to $f(c)=4$. So $c^2=4$.

Comment: <> means "does not equal". Yes that is exactly what I had in mind. And c^2 = 4 only when c = +/-2

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ be a real.

$$\lim_{x\to a,x\in\Bbb Q}f(x)=4$$

$$\lim_{x\to a,x\notin \Bbb Q}f(x)=a^2$$

the function is continuous only at $x=\pm 2$.